# Linking two object in a trigger when I can an External Id

Tags: externalid

In my before insert trigger I want to link the incoming record with an existing record.
I have a lookup from Lead to Account and the incoming Lead includes the value of the External ID of the Account.
How can I create this "link" using the External ID without querying the DB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look here:
http://blogs.developerforce.com/engineering/2012/02/cascade-insert-with-external-id-fields.html

I think you can do something like this:

```
Account a = new Account();
a.External_Id__c = ‘myExtId’;
Lead.Account__r = a;
```

Comment: see http://www.pocketsoap.com/weblog/2008/09/index.html for additional examples

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this syntax works in a 'before insert' trigger - I believe it only works in a DML statement?

Answer (score -1):

**Edit : Upsert is mandatory only when matching on a single entity (i.e. update/insert an account and match to an existing account, if it exists ) or relating records using Data Loader.**

Matching on External Ids works natively only when done via an [Upsert operation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml_upsert.htm).
Depending on how you are inserting the Leads, you can do one of :

If Dataloaded, then use the mapping file to match Lead to Account using the External Id

If using code, then rather than doing the matching retrospectively in a trigger, this would work better when you're inserting (upserting) the Lead.

```
Lead l ....
Account acc = new Account(External_Id__c = 'ABC');
l.Account__r = acc;
upsert  l ;
```

Comment: that's not true,the ability to resolve foreign keys via an external Id on the related record work for create, update & upsert.

Comment: My bad, thanks @superfell, was just trying that out now, for some reason I remember reading it was only upsert - but that's clearly via the data loader or for updating the record itself using an external Id - so upsert account externalIdfield. Cheers.